# Disable Props from Being Displayed in "data-page" attribute in react-inertia

Tags: reactjs, inertiajs

I use React. Is there a way to not show this data-page attribute? Thanks
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8fsy.png)

Comment: Are you using any browser extensions? Disable Gramarly and try again.

Comment: Yes, I use the extension .and I don't think it has anything to do with it because it still shows up. I think it should be hidden in React, but I don't know how! thanks